# Trying to store and retrieve App data using SharedPreferences, but it's not returning desired data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve the location for each specific post (Latitude and Longitude) and I am doing this the following way, see code below. I don't understand why I am getting this error:

> Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.e.events.Model.Post

I have used this code in other Activities and it worked just fine.

What I need to happen is because each post has its own specific `postid`, I want to store that in SharedPreferences and then look through Firebase to find that specific `postid` and return that post's specific location Latitude and Longitude. Anyone can explain to me why I am getting this error?

[image: Firebase Setup]

**MapsActivityUser.java**

```
public class MapsActivityUser extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    String postid;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_user);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        postid = preferences.getString("postid", "none");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(postid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    if (post != null) {
                        double latitude = post.getLocation().getLatitude();
                        double longitude = post.getLocation().getLongitude();

                        LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Event location"));
                        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 10));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityUser.this, "Event doesn't have location on Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Post.java**

```
public class Post {

    private String postid;
    private String postimage;
    private String description;
    private String publisher;
    private String text_event;
    private String text_location;
    private String text_date_time;
    private Long timestamp;
    private double Latitude;
    private double Longitude;
    private LocationHelper locationHelper;

    public Post(String description, String postId, String postImage, String publisher, Long timestamp,
                String text_event, String text_location, String text_date_time, double latitude, double longitude, LocationHelper location) {
        this.postid = postid;
        this.postimage = postimage;
        this.description = description;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.text_event = text_event;
        this.text_location = text_location;
        this.text_date_time = text_date_time;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
        this.locationHelper = location;
    }

    public Post() {
    }

    public String getPostid() {
        return postid;
    }

    public void setPostid(String postid) {
        this.postid = postid;
    }

    public String getPostimage() {
        return postimage;
    }

    public void setPostimage(String postimage) {
        this.postimage = postimage;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getText_event() {
        return text_event;
    }

    public void setText_event(String text_event) {
        this.text_event = text_event;
    }

    public String getText_location() {
        return text_location;
    }

    public void setText_location(String text_location) {
        this.text_location = text_location;
    }

    public String getText_date_time() {
        return text_date_time;
    }

    public void setText_date_time(String text_date_time) {
        this.text_date_time = text_date_time;
    }

    public Long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return Latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        Latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return Longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        Longitude = longitude;
    }

    public LocationHelper getLocation() {
        return locationHelper;
    }

    public void setLocation(LocationHelper location) {
        this.locationHelper = location;
    }
}
```

**LocationHelper.java**

```
public class LocationHelper {

    private double Latitude;
    private double Longitude;

    public LocationHelper(double latitude, double longitude) {
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
    }

    public LocationHelper() {
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return Latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        Latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return Longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        Longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.e.events.Model.LocationHelper
>   com.e.events.Model.Post.getLocation()' on a null object reference
>           at com.e.events.Map.MapsActivityUser$1.onDataChange(MapsActivityUser.java:53)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:75)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:63)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:55)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking your query I can see you passed `post_id` so it will give you directly the post data. You don't need to iterate through the `DataSnapshot`:

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        if (post != null) {
            double latitude = post.getLocation().getLatitude();
            double longitude = post.getLocation().getLongitude();

            LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Event location"));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 10));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivityUser.this, "Event doesn't have location on Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Modify Something like this :

You don't need to add Longitude and latitude

```
public class Post {

    private String postid;
    private String postimage;
    private String description;
    private String publisher;
    private String text_event;
    private String text_location;
    private String text_date_time;
    private Long timestamp;
    private Location locationHelper;

    public Post(String description, String postId, String postImage, String publisher, Long timestamp,
                String text_event, String text_location, String text_date_time, double latitude, double longitude, LocationHelper location) {
        this.postid = postid;
        this.postimage = postimage;
        this.description = description;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.text_event = text_event;
        this.text_location = text_location;
        this.text_date_time = text_date_time;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
        this.locationHelper = location;
    }

    public Post() {
    }

    public String getPostid() {
        return postid;
    }

    public void setPostid(String postid) {
        this.postid = postid;
    }

    public String getPostimage() {
        return postimage;
    }

    public void setPostimage(String postimage) {
        this.postimage = postimage;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getText_event() {
        return text_event;
    }

    public void setText_event(String text_event) {
        this.text_event = text_event;
    }

    public String getText_location() {
        return text_location;
    }

    public void setText_location(String text_location) {
        this.text_location = text_location;
    }

    public String getText_date_time() {
        return text_date_time;
    }

    public void setText_date_time(String text_date_time) {
        this.text_date_time = text_date_time;
    }

    public Long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }


    public Location getLocation() {
        return locationHelper;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.locationHelper = location;
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code to reflect yours above, but now I am just getting the Toast message. No marker on map is showing up as it should be.. And all posts clearly have a saved location Latitude and Longitude

Comment: Please log the data your retriving inside dataSnapshot

Comment: Okay man, so I just posted the logcat when the app crashes and it says that ```post.getLocation``` is null but I don't know why that is because I have the ```LocationHelper``` class where I stored location data. I posted the logcat above

Comment: ```D/: onDataChange: This is what it returnsDataSnapshot { key = -LzmZfxVKI167NeI5fSH, value = null }``` this is what I get back, but why is that if I have the ```LocationHelper``` model class and the ```Post``` model class?

Comment: Sorry for late reply but you need to modify your model class

Comment: It's okay man. How would you change it and which one Post.java or LocationHelper.java?

Comment: I suggest you to make one more class Location then put the location getter setter inside post

Comment: Isn't that what I already did? I created a seperate class LocationHelper for Latitude and Longitude coordinates and then added the getter and setter to Post.java at the very bottom... Or is that wrong?

Comment: Please check the edit and join [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207021/firebase-user-helper-room)